# How to compute the Auger transition rate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-of-states, fermis-golden-rule

I've been working on computing the Auger transition rate for an exotic atom, one where an electron has been replaced by a particle of arbitrary mass and (integer) charge. I've been closely following the work in [this](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.89.189) paper but am a bit puzzled by the origins of the formulas used.

In particular, equation 2 of this paper states that the transition rate is $$\Gamma=\frac{1}{\hbar}|\langle f|V|i\rangle|^2\tag{2}$$ which is close to, but not exactly, Fermi's golden rule: $$\Gamma=\frac{2\pi}{\hbar}|\langle f|V|i\rangle|^2\rho(E_f).$$ I would naively assume that there is some way to see that $\rho(E_f) = \frac{1}{2\pi}$ but that is certainly not the case for the free electron in the final state. I feel like there is something fundamental I am missing here either about Fermi's golden rule or the density of states.